# Installing WindowBuilder ZIP version on Eclipse 4.2 Juno

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I'm trying to install WindowBuilder by using the ZIP Release version. How should I install it properly? Should I just copy and paste the WB's plugin files to the Eclipse's plugin folder?

If I still need to use the Update Manager, what link should I add? Is it the directory of index.html found inside the zip file?

I don't want to install WB using the Update Link of eclipse for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help ->Install New Software ->Add -> and click Archive button and browse to your file location    then install as usual.